# Windows 8 can't seem to use or install any virtual devices

Tags: windows-8, drivers

I have a new Windows 8 Pro x64 installation that I can't seemingly use any virtual devices.

Any time it attempt to us the built in ISO mounting of Windows 8 it gives me a generic "can't mount" type error.

If I install Slysoft Virtual Clone Drive it hangs during installation at the point it's attempting to install the driver.

If I install Daemon Tools Lite, it hangs on installation at "Updating virtual devices".

Any thoughts?

Comment: Virtual Clone Drive works for me. If the generic ones fails, make sure your installed SD reader gets a high drive letter (like W:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemingly had to reinstall Windows 8. This time I had it do a clean installation instead of the upgrade from Windows 7.